# Using sed for a generic substitutioner

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I am being handed a file that has different configuration entries
Lines from example input:

```
       "configuration_name_1": "configuration_value_1"
  configuration_name_2 : configuration_value_2 
  "configuration_name_3": 'configuration_value_3'
  "configuration_name_4": configuration_value_4
```

These values are supposed to act as substitutes in different files (by location and type- JSON, yaml, etc). There is no way to implement a unified file type for the whole solution and adding additional tools to the host is out of the question.

I have managed to trim all of the configurations to a **key:value**  format in a temporary file. 
Example:

```
configuration_name_1:configuration_value_1
configuration_name_2:configuration_value_2 
configuration_name_3:configuration_value_3
```

The next step is to override values in different files. example.yaml file contains (keep in mind, yaml is indentation-sensitive):

```
  configuration_name_1: "test"
  configuration_name_2:  123
```

example.yaml  must be changed to :

```
  configuration_name_1: "configuration_value_1"
  configuration_name_2:  configuration_value_2
```

example.json contains

```
{
 "configuration_name_3": "abcd"
 "configuration_name_4":  5555
}
```

example.json must be changed to :

```
{
 "configuration_name_3": "configuration_value_3"
 "configuration_name_4":  configuration_value_4
}
```

Is there a way to override the the values for the specific keys in the target files, while ignoring the formatting?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Added current state of file contents and target state of file contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is for doing simple s/old/new on individual strings, **that is all**. For anything else you should be using awk, e.g. with GNU awk for gensub() and the third arg to match():

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == FNR {
    tag = gensub(/:.*/,"",1)
    val = gensub(/[^:]+:/,"",1)
    gsub(/^\s*["\047]?|["\047]?\s*$/,"",tag)
    gsub(/^\s*["\047]?|["\047]?\s*$/,"",val)
    tag2val[tag] = val
    next
}
match($0,/^(\s*([^:]+)[:[:space:]]+)(.*)$/,a) {
    tag = a[2]
    gsub(/^"|"$/,"",tag)
    if ( tag in tag2val ) {
        delim = (gsub(/^"|"$/,"",a[3]) ? "\"" : "")
        $0 = a[1] delim tag2val[tag] delim
    }
}
{ print }

$ cat foo.map
       "configuration_name_1": "configuration_value_1"
  configuration_name_2 : configuration_value_2
  "configuration_name_3": 'configuration_value_3'
  "configuration_name_4": configuration_value_4

$ awk -f tst.awk foo.map example.yaml example.json
  configuration_name_1: "configuration_value_1"
  configuration_name_2:  configuration_value_2
{
 "configuration_name_3": "configuration_value_3"
 "configuration_name_4":  configuration_value_4
}
```

and to make the changes "inplace" if that's what you want:

```
$ cat example.yaml
  configuration_name_1: "test"
  configuration_name_2:  123

$ cat example.json
{
 "configuration_name_3": "abcd"
 "configuration_name_4":  5555
}

$ awk -i inplace -f tst.awk foo.map example.yaml example.json

$ cat example.yaml
  configuration_name_1: "configuration_value_1"
  configuration_name_2:  configuration_value_2

$ cat example.json
{
 "configuration_name_3": "configuration_value_3"
 "configuration_name_4":  configuration_value_4
}
```